# Why there is no source or sink at point with zero divergence?

Tags: vector-analysis

Suppose that $\operatorname{div} \mathbf{F} = 0$ at some point $x$.

$$\operatorname{div} \mathbf{F} = \lim_{V \to x} \frac{\Phi (S)}{|V|}$$

Flux across surface $S$ (when volume $V$ is infinitesimally small) isn't equal to $0$, it's almost equal to $0$. Hence there is source or sink at point $x$.

I don't understand where is mistake in my reasoning.

Thanks.

Comment: @coffeemath: I mean if flux across small surface is positive or negative then there is source or sink inside surface (at point x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there is a problem right from the definitions. Generally agreed is:

- a source is a point, $x$, where ($\mbox{div}F \gt 0$) ;
- a sink is a point, $x$, where ($\mbox{div} F \lt 0$).

This makes the answer to the question straightforward but not very helpful, I imagine. Now, may help two remarks:

1. if $\mbox{div}F=0$ at $x$, then when $V$ gets smaller around $x$, $\Phi(S)$ gets smaller too, but "more smaller", if I dare to speak so.
2. the divergence in dimension 1 is just the derivative. For a function such as $F(x)=(x^2)$ (which can be viewed as a 1-dimensional vector field!), we have $\frac{F(0+h)-F(0)}{h} = \frac{h^2}{h}$. We have $(\mbox{div}F)(0)=F'(0) =0$ as a limit, and yet one wouldn't argue that $h^2$ is not $0$ to conclude that the origin is a source or sink (which it isn't). May be your mistake in the reasoning is similar.